# Set life time for image cache by using Android Universa Image Loader Library

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader

In my android project, I am using Android-Universal-Image-Loader Lib ([HERE](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)) to load image from internet.

I want to save cache of those images for a period of time (example 1 day).

After the life time ends, it will load image again from internet (when my application starts). Otherwise, it will use cache.

Please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `LimitedAgeDiskCache` for that.

```
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context);
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        ...
        .diskCache(new LimitedAgeDiskCache(cacheDir, 24 * 60 * 60))
        .build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```